# Fillin question with exam till the end of the line

Tags: exam

I am creating a test using the *exam* package. I do have some fillin questions using the `\fillin` command.

I know that that I can specify the fillin lines length with an absoulte value using `\fillin[correct answer][5cm]`, but I would like the line to stretch until the end of the line.

Is that possible?

Comment: \fillin[{\color{red}$25a^2+70a+49$}][\linewidth]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fillin` command seems to accept only absolute length values. However, you can leave out the `fillin` and put a default horizontal line with `\hrulefill`. It is possible to add something after the line, in the MWE below there is a space and a period (`\ .`).

A disadvantage is that the correct answer is not specified, which means that it is not shown in answer mode. A solution is to combine `fillin` with a horizontal line, however the baseline differs slightly. Using the package `xhfill` you can adjust the baseline. Results using different viewers, different zoom levels, or in print are not guaranteed to be consistent.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question The magic word is \hrulefill\ .
\question Where is the baseline? \fillin[low]\hrulefill
\question The normal word is \fillin[correct answer][5cm]\xrfill[-1pt]{0.2mm}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work out of the box, but your alternative is great, too. Thanks.
One question: What does `MWE` stand for?

Comment: MWE stands for Minimal Working Example, which is the smallest complete document that illustrates a problem or a solution, or a starting point for a document where you want to add something. Adding this to a post makes it much easier for others to reproduce a problem or a solution. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that